# Consulta em um relacionamento Many to Many no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento

Galera, estou "empacado" em um problema relativo a um relatório de um cliente.

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento:

- Modulo (id, nome)
- Associado (id, nome, superior_id)
- Associados_Modulos (modulo_id, associado_id, turma, matriculado, cursando, desistiu)

O que eu preciso é: **listar todos os módulo relativos a um "superior_id"**, com as seguintes informações:

- **quantas turmas pertencem a esse módulo** = aqui o primeiro problema: turma é um varchar.. apenas uma descrição, por exemplo: Turma 45 das 08:00h as 21:00h.
- quantos associados relativos a esse módulo estão presentes
- quantos associados relativos a esse módulo estão matriculados
- quantos associados relativos a esse módulo desistiram

Resumindo: não sei qual a melhor maneira de fazer este relacionamento (many to many?), e qual melhor maneira de fazer esta consulta, principalmente por turma ser um varchar e não um ḿodulo qualquer (o qual eu poderia fazer um count através do relacionamento padrão).

Qualquer informação que precisarem me avise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mais ou menos assim:
Essa é a melhor forma de utilizar, ou seja, com [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) visto que o Eloquent fica meio engessado.

```
DB::table('associados_modulos')            
        ->join('modulo', 'associados_modulos.modulo_id', '=', 'modulo.id')
        ->join('associado', 'associados_modulos.associado_id', '=', 'associado.id')
        ->where('superior_id', $codigoSuperior_id)
        ->groupBy('modulo_id')            
        ->select(DB::raw('count(turma) qtdeturmas, sum(matriculado) qtdematriculados, count(desistiu) qtdedesistiu, modulo_id'))
        ->get();
```